# Generalization of positive definiteness for a non-smooth quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I have a "quadratic form" defined as follows:

$$f(\vec x) = \sum_{i<j} c_{ij} x_i x_j + \sum_i a_i(x_i) x_i^2$$

where the coefficients $c_{ij}$ are fixed constants, but the coefficients $a_i(x_i)$ can depend on the *sign* of $x_i$:

$$a_i(x_i) = \cases{
  a_i^+ & $x_i \ge 0$ \\
  a_i^- & $x_i < 0$}$$

I assume that both $a_i^+, a_i^-$ are positive. I also assume all the quantities here are real for simplicity.

I need to determine whether $f(\vec x)$ is "positive definite", that is, $f(\vec x)\ge 0$ for all $\vec x$.

If $a_i^+ = a_i^-$ for all $i$, then this question reduces to computing the eigenvalues of a matrix with entries $(a_i; c_{ij})$ and checking whether they are all positive.

In my case, where $a_i^+$ can be different from $a_i^-$, it seems that I have to compute an eigenvalue decomposition for each possible matrix (one for each quadrant, so exponentially many), and if the eigenvector points in the direction of the quadrant, check the sign of the corresponding eigenvalue. But this approach is combinatorially intractable.

Is there a better way of characterizing when $f(\vec x) \ge 0$ for all $\vec x$?

Comment: Two obvious observations:
1. If you replace $a_i=min(a_i^_,a_i^-)$ and the corresponding quadratic form is positive definite then f is positive definite.
2. If you check positive definiteness for predefined sign's of the $x_i's$ and you have a term $c_{ij}x_ix_j$ which is always positive it suffices to show positive definitess with a $c_{ij}$ changed towards 0.

Comment: You could replace $x_i=u_i-v_i$ with $u_i, v_i\geq 0$, $u_i v_i=0$. Then we have $a_i(x_i)x_i^2= a_i^+ u_i^2+a_i^- v_i^2$. Hence you will get a standard quadratic form and you need to prove that for nonnegative $u_i, v_i$ it is positive. You then do not have exponentially many cases. The system is however twice as large.